# Why is Bitmap not displayed in ListView

Tags: listview, delphi, bitmap, listviewitem

In Delphi Rio 10.3.3 I created a new FMX application and placed three components on the form.  TButton, TImageControl, and TListView which is made about 600x400.  In the Button1Click I have:

```
    var LItem: TListViewItem;      
    begin
    LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
    LItem.Height := 250;
    LItem.Bitmap.LoadThumbnailFromFile('My.jpg', 160, 120, False); 
    LItem.Text := 'Text';
    ImageControl1.Bitmap := LItem.Bitmap; 
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(LItem.Bitmap.Width) + ' x ' + 
                IntToStr(LItem.Bitmap.Height));
```

What I don't understand is how the ListViewItem's Bitmap can show expected dimensions, which are much smaller than elements in the ListView, and that Bitmap can be copied to a separate ImageControl where it looks as expected, yet the ListViewItem's Bitmap does not appear in the ListView.  The ListViewItem's Text does appear in the ListView, but whether I keep that or remove it, the Bitmap is not displayed.  Dropping the thumbnail sizes to half those values does not cause the image in Bitmap to be displayed.

Am I missing a step that applies to displaying ListViewItem.Bitmap in a ListView?

Like, how is it that LItem.Text appears without anything other than giving it a value while LItem.Bitmap requires some other handling?

I'm looking at how the sample app called SampleListViewAddThumbnailAndCaption works, but it's a bit convoluted and relies on ListViewItem.BitmapRef which is not exactly a documented property so it might be just a kludge because it points to a non-visible Image.  Further, the sample app uses a value of "TI" for the thumbnail name and I haven't found out if that's meaningful or another dummy.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to employ the technique using TListItemImage found in the sample app ListViewAddThumbnailAndCaption, but it was not immediately apparent, so though I had tried that approach before posting my question, the fact that it didn't seem to work led me to my post.

The reason that approach hadn't worked is that the images were being positioned outside of the ListView's dimensions.  Once I fixed that, the rest becomes a matter of tweaking.